# How to change images path when converting AsciiDoc file containing diagrams to html using Asciidoctor Ruby API?

Tags: ruby, asciidoc, asciidoctor

Lets suppose there is a web based documentation available at docs.project

### Directory structure

```
/ - project root
    /docs - documentation files in asciidoc format
      index.adoc - documentation entry point
    /public - public directory
generate.rb
```

### Desirable workflow

1. I change documentation source in /docs directory.
2. I commit and push changes.
3. When pushing, the server runs `ruby <project_root>/generate.rb` command that rewrites the html presentation of the documentation.

index.adoc

```
= Documetation

Some text

[plantuml]
....
Client --> Server: Request
Server --> Client: Response
....
```

generate.rb

```rb
require 'asciidoctor'
require 'asciidoctor-diagram'

ROOT = File.dirname(__FILE__)
entry = ROOT + '/docs/index.adoc'
outdir = ROOT + '/public'
Asciidoctor.convert_file entry, to_dir: outdir, mkdirs: true
```

### Problem

Current `generate.rb` script puts index.html file in `public` while images go to `docs` thus they are not available when you open docs.project in browser.

How to specify the images path?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `imagesdir`

You could move all your images that are being used in your `index.adoc` into the public folder(since this is your output folder) and can set `imagesdir` document attribute like:

```
:imagesdir: ../public/
```

inside your `index.adoc` file. You could learn more about `imagesdir` [here](https://asciidoctor.org/docs/user-manual/#setting-the-location-of-images)

Comment: I tried this option, exactly like you offered. But looks like "../" does not work here. Images go to /docs/public instead of /public.

Comment: did you move your images to the `/root/public` folder? because this works for me. even if you don't set the `imagesdir` attribute, the `html` file generated uses the absolute path which should work if the images and generated html files are in same folder.

Comment: I want to implement something similar to webpack bundling: I push changes in source (index.adoc) and html is rebuilt on the server. Html and images are not included in the repository.

So I want Asciidoctor to put images where I specified. Moving them to `/public` by myself  I consider workaround.

Comment: can you share your output `index.html` file after it is generated. just want to know how `src` attributes of `image` tag looks like.?

Comment: `<img src="../public/diag-e37daaa155c4004d06060e0e019fa387.png" alt="diag e37daaa155c4004d06060e0e019fa387" width="157" height="156">`

Comment: and what if when you change your `:imagesdir: ../docs/` ? what is the output then?

Comment: <img src="../docs/diag-c10e4d55a1661e5727b9de4110653afc.png" alt="diag c10e4d55a1661e5727b9de4110653afc" width="157" height="156">

Comment: and does this hash `c10e4...` is in your image name itself? I would really like to help and these comments are not helping can we zoom/skype about this?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem should be that when using the Ruby API, the default safe mode is set to `:secure`, which should prevent access to files which reside outside of the parent directory of the source file. I am assuming `to_dir` is allowed to write the file, while `plantuml` goes through a different generation process (probably initially generates the image and then includes it, preventing access to the directory). In any case, you have two options.

1. Use unsafe mode with:

```
Asciidoctor.convert_file entry, to_dir: outdir, mkdirs: true, safe: :unsafe
```

It is probably not the best solution, use only if you are running it with controlled content (and no one can put something like `include::/etc/passwd[]` in the adoc source).

2. Change the base_dir with:

```
Asciidoctor.convert_file entry, base_dir: '.', to_dir: outdir, mkdirs: true
```

Which should work, assuming your directory structure looks like:

```
.
├── docs
│   └── index.adoc
├── generate.rb
└── public
```